# SAPUI5 Popup do not open for the second time

Tags: popup, sapui5

I am using `JSFragment` to display data in a View. The JSFragment(popup) has several buttons and lists. While running the app, when I click on the buttons in the fragment, it works fine. But when I again try to access the popup I get error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addStyleClass' of undefined adding element with duplicate id 'popoverNavCon--me

I have defined few references to IDs in fragment using `this.createId()`. I am not able to find my error.

Comment: You will need to use createId for the fragment as well. Read [this]( 
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/5da591c5a5a54740948acfe56b22fbc3.html) and [this](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/030fcd14963048218488048f407f8f34.html)

Answer (score 0):

Before second opening-call you have to destroy the one you created before via 
`sap.ui.getCore().byId("'popoverNavCon--me").destroy();// use the full ID!`

Comment: I am already using this statement:                                       popover.attachAfterClose ( function(){ popover.destroy();} );   So no need to use yours i guess.

Comment: the error message is clear, you are creating an element with an id which is already created. no Options on this.